# Nested routes in Rails with an alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I have a primary model for my project, Place.rb with a places_controller, and I've currently got it exactly the way I want for the users end of my project.  With a nested photos controller, review, etc.

I want now to create a management resource which is mostly just an alias for Places, with its own nested resources, some of them overlapping, some of them new.

I tried creating a new controller for it called Manage, but I'm having a hard time with routes.  I'm not quite sure the hangup is, but I figure I'm doing something very wrong.  I had little difficulty when I was using Places as controller to a real model and nesting other resources below it.

But for example trying to create a new record for a nested resource doesn't route correctly.

I can get a route path like `new_manage_room_path(@place)` for a link_to to work fine.  But

for creating a New announcement in a form:

`form_for manage_room_path(@place)` doesn't work correctly given a valid id. I've tried many other combinations supplying the object and :url.

Should I avoid using a separate controller and just create an alias or what is the special routing for this purpose?

```
map.resources :manage, :collection => { :upcoming => [ :post, :get ], :pending => [ :post, :get ] } do |manage|
  manage.resources :rooms
  manage.resources :room_rates, :as => :rates
  manage.resources :availables
  manage.resources :manage_bookings, :as => :bookings
end

map.resources :places do |place|
  place.resources :bookings
  place.resources :photos, :collection => { :sort => :post }
  place.resources :reviews, :only => [ :index, :show ]
end



manage_rooms GET    /manage/:manage_id/rooms(.:format)               {:controller=>"rooms", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /manage/:manage_id/rooms(.:format)               {:controller=>"rooms", :action=>"create"}
                   new_manage_room GET    /manage/:manage_id/rooms/new(.:format)           {:controller=>"rooms", :action=>"new"}
                  edit_manage_room GET    /manage/:manage_id/rooms/:id/edit(.:format)      {:controller=>"rooms", :action=>"edit"}
                       manage_room GET    /manage/:manage_id/rooms/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"rooms", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /manage/:manage_id/rooms/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"rooms", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /manage/:manage_id/rooms/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"rooms", :action=>"destroy"}
                 manage_room_rates GET    /manage/:manage_id/rates(.:format)               {:controller=>"room_rates", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /manage/:manage_id/rates(.:format)               {:controller=>"room_rates", :action=>"create"}
              new_manage_room_rate GET    /manage/:manage_id/rates/new(.:format)           {:controller=>"room_rates", :action=>"new"}
             edit_manage_room_rate GET    /manage/:manage_id/rates/:id/edit(.:format)      {:controller=>"room_rates", :action=>"edit"}
                  manage_room_rate GET    /manage/:manage_id/rates/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"room_rates", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /manage/:manage_id/rates/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"room_rates", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /manage/:manage_id/rates/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"room_rates", :action=>"destroy"}
                 manage_availables GET    /manage/:manage_id/availables(.:format)          {:controller=>"availables", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /manage/:manage_id/availables(.:format)          {:controller=>"availables", :action=>"create"}
              new_manage_available GET    /manage/:manage_id/availables/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"availables", :action=>"new"}
             edit_manage_available GET    /manage/:manage_id/availables/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"availables", :action=>"edit"}
                  manage_available GET    /manage/:manage_id/availables/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"availables", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /manage/:manage_id/availables/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"availables", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /manage/:manage_id/availables/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"availables", :action=>"destroy"}
            manage_manage_bookings GET    /manage/:manage_id/bookings(.:format)            {:controller=>"manage_bookings", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /manage/:manage_id/bookings(.:format)            {:controller=>"manage_bookings", :action=>"create"}
         new_manage_manage_booking GET    /manage/:manage_id/bookings/new(.:format)        {:controller=>"manage_bookings", :action=>"new"}
        edit_manage_manage_booking GET    /manage/:manage_id/bookings/:id/edit(.:format)   {:controller=>"manage_bookings", :action=>"edit"}
             manage_manage_booking GET    /manage/:manage_id/bookings/:id(.:format)        {:controller=>"manage_bookings", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /manage/:manage_id/bookings/:id(.:format)        {:controller=>"manage_bookings", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /manage/:manage_id/bookings/:id(.:format)        {:controller=>"manage_bookings", :action=>"destroy"}
                    pending_manage POST   /manage/pending(.:format)                        {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"pending"}
                                   GET    /manage/pending(.:format)                        {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"pending"}
                   upcoming_manage POST   /manage/upcoming(.:format)                       {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"upcoming"}
                                   GET    /manage/upcoming(.:format)                       {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"upcoming"}
                      manage_index GET    /manage(.:format)                                {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /manage(.:format)                                {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"create"}
                        new_manage GET    /manage/new(.:format)                            {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"new"}
                       edit_manage GET    /manage/:id/edit(.:format)                       {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"edit"}
                            manage GET    /manage/:id(.:format)                            {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /manage/:id(.:format)                            {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /manage/:id(.:format)                            {:controller=>"manage", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: Usually `form_for @place` should do the trick. Paste `rake routes` and the contents of  your `routes.rb` file so we can investigate further.

Comment: Yeah... usually it does.  But in this case it isn't working.  When I couldn't figure it out I thought it might have something to do with the fact that the root resource wasn't based on a real model, but merely there to differentiate the places model between users and manager aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<% form_for @new_room, :url => manage_rooms_path(@place)  do |f| %>
```

or maybe it will work this way:

```
<% form_for manage_rooms_path(@place, @new_room)  do |f| %>
```

`@new_room` is new instance of Room model, so in controller add:

```
@new_room = Room.new
```